# How to power Coral edge-tpu dev-board off a battery

Tags: google-coral

I bought a google Edge TPU Coral dev board (https://coral.ai/products/dev-board/). It’s an amazing device and I would like to include it in a robotics project. However: I was wondering how I should power it if it can’t be connected to a wall-socket. 
I thought of the following options:

- Connect it to a USB-C powerbank. Easy choice, but I don’t have any
- Connect it to a normal powerbank with a USB->USB-C converter. I was wondering if this can damage the board in any way
- Connect it to a LIPO battery with a 5V BEC. I looked at the data sheet and couldn’t find a specific place to attach my own power source outside of the USB-C input. Is there any way to accomplish this feat?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, I'm from the coral team and just wanted to let you know that this is an interesting query that we have not tested yet. This is also harder to test during this pandemic, but I'll bring it up on our weekly meeting tomorrow to see if can come up with some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you need any help or want me to test something: let me know.

Comment: Also: as one interesting remark: I did a small robotics project with it (detect pigeons) and one other problems I had was that I wanted to have 2 usb inputs/outputs (webcam + motor-driver). I plugged in a usb-c to usb converter which worked wonders :) Might be something to add to your site.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for you info, I'll get back with you after my meeting tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: I decided to be brave and just try it out. Here you see a 5V power bank with normal USB output, a USB -> USB micro cable, and a usb-micro to usb-c adapter. This could power the coral dev board, it booted, and I could ssh to it (although I guess it would be good to look at the power draw when running heavy neural network inferencing).

[image]

Comment: Did you have an update on your project? Looking at doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried out PoE cable? I am wondering if it is able to connect to PoE cable? So that it could be powered up using switch via PoE cable?

Comment: I have not tried this. Let me know if you manage to do this :)

Comment: Oh I see, okay, I will let you know if I managed to get it done